# When running angular project on localhost, I can type in any url for my website, but on apache server I can't

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular-routing

I'm running an Angular 6 project using `ng serve` on my local dev machine. I have the following endpoints for example:

- /login
- /cart

When my project is running on localhost:4200, I can type in any of the following and they are all valid (browser will load the corresponding page successfully):

- localhost:4200
- localhost:4200/login
- localhost:4200/cart

However, when I build the dist folder and push the contents to my production server, I try to access the site through the same urls and it doesn't work:

- http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx          -- works
- http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/login    -- doesn't work
- http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/cart     -- doesn't work

The one's that don't work respond with a 404 not found error. In the console it says:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

How come the behaviour is different on local development vs production servers? How can I allow users to route directly to a specific endpoint like http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/cart?

This will also fix my other issue. I added the functionality that if the user actually types in the wrong url, they will get a 404 error (as expected). I have configured in my app-routing.module.ts file that 404 errors will be redirected to a custom component. This no longer works however.

This is how I build by project:

```
ng build --configuration=staging  # --configuration=staging specifies that the build should use the staging environment listed in environments folder
```

The files are stored in the /var/www/html folder on the server and it is running apache2.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation, angular servers must redirect all requests to index.html each server in its form of configuration.

https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Answer (score -1):

Everything has to route via index.html to work Please use the config in the below link to make it work https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Deploying-prod-build-to-Apache-2